# How to disable oh-my-zsh features only in PyCharm terminal

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, dot-files

When using the shell in PyCharm, I have noticed that when I type quickly, the auto-complete feature will cause characters to be dropped.

Is there a convenient way to start /bin/zsh and cause it to ignore `$ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` - maybe point to an alternative .zshrc file or something?

One possibility would be to set an env variable as a flag tell whether or not to load the plugin.

Looking for better/others suggestions and/or validation that this is a feasible approach, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `ZDOTDIR` environment variable to tell zsh to look for its configuration file in a different directory.

Alternatively, you can modify your `.zshrc` to check its parent process. Something like

```
parent_process_name=$(ps -o comm= $PPID)
if [[ "$parent_process_name" == "some-program" ]]; then …
```

Check what the actual command name is for `some-program`. If it's `python`, you'll need to check the command's arguments. Something like

```
parent_process_args=$(ps -o args= $PPID)
if [[ "$parent_process_name" == python(2|3|)\ PyCharm* ]]; then …
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
if [ -z “$INTELLIJ_ENVIRONMENT_READER” ]; then
  source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
fi
```